# Multiple Submit Changes and Exceptions

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception

Simple scenarios.

Reading data from one source and saving to SQL database using LinqToSQL. 
There are many rows in the file. It's possible that SQL exception can occur for some rows but we want to ignore it (log exception) and still save the rest of the data.

Currently we do submitchanges after each row of input data. The first time SQL Exception is encountered none of the following rows can be processed because the same exceptions seems to be resubmitted.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: You would probably want to create a new context instance for each save as it will simply keep trying to save the same changes over and over again.

Comment: As far as I know LINQ process each "row" at a time for a given command i.e. on updating it'd update every object and them save.
So I think you would have to make you own function, but not sure (hence a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: Creating separate data context for each is not really practical since before the update the system processes data from the context and will either update or insert object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I seem to have found a solution and wanted to share it.

The way to do this is to clear out all pending changes before proceeding. So if the SubmitChanges fails I now call this extension method on the datacontext - RejectPendingChanges().

When the next row is processed it now longer tries to resubmit bad data.

public static void RejectPendingChanges(this System.Data.Linq.DataContext db){

```
        var chgset = db.GetChangeSet();
        if (chgset != null)
        {
            foreach (object objToInsert in chgset.Inserts)
            {
               db.GetTable(objToInsert.GetType()).DeleteOnSubmit(objToInsert);
            }
            //Undo deletes
            foreach (object objToDelete in chgset.Deletes)
            {
                db.GetTable(objToDelete.GetType()).InsertOnSubmit(objToDelete);
            }
            ///this._DB.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, chgset.Deletes);
            db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, chgset.Updates);
        }
    }
```